# @api recordId not passing to my class

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer

I am not able to save my record.
What am I doing wrong? If I insert the Id in my code it is working...

```
public with sharing class ScheduleClass {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Product_Schedule__c submitSchedule(String recordId, string psName, string psDescription){
        Product_Schedule__c psObj = new Product_Schedule__c();
        psObj.Invoice_Schedule__c=recordId;
        psObj.Product_Name__c=psName;
        psObj.Product_Description__c=psDescription;
 
        insert psObj;
        return psObj;
    }
}
```

here is my JS

```
import {LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

import submitSchedule from '@salesforce/apex/ScheduleClass.submitSchedule';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


export default class ScheduleClass extends LightningElement {

    @track psObjName;
    @track psObjDescription;
    @api recordId;
    @track errorMsg;

   psHandleChange(event){
        if(event.target.name == 'psName'){
        this.psObjName = event.target.value;
        }
        if(event.target.name == 'psDescription'){
        this.psObjDescription = event.target.value;  
        }

 }

 submitAction(){
    submitSchedule({recordId:this.recordId,psName:this.psObjName,psDescription:this.psObjDescription})
    .then(result=>{
        this.recordId = result.Id;
        window.console.log('recordId ' + this.recordId);       
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title:'Success!',
            message:'Record created successfully',
            variant:'success'
          });
          this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);

    })
    .catch(error =>{
       this.errorMsg=error.message;
       window.console.log(this.error);
    });

 }
}
```

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: You can't write to an `@api` variable. I believe you mean to send an event to the parent component with the new record Id. Without more context, it's hard to provide any further advice.

Comment: If you are placing the component in the record page and expecting to get the record ID automatically based on the context, you need to explicitly use '@api recordId', as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context). Custom variable 'psRecordId' is not context aware.

Comment: @aruf, you are right! I just realised that... On the record page I added the {recordId} and I can see it. What I am trying to do is to save the record and I absolutely need to pass the recordId to save the record as it is a child. So why in my submitSchedule fonction recordId:this.recordId is not working?

Comment: @Eric I suggest you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/333523/edit) your question to correct the `psRecordId` to show where you are using `recordId` instead.

Comment: I edited my code with recordId.
The variable doesn't seems to go to my class.

Comment: You should pass it as `psRecordId: this.recordId` i.e., `submitSchedule({psRecordId:this.recordId, psName:this.psObjName, psDescription:this.psObjDescription})`. Note that the `recordId` is context aware within LWC, but there is no change in your apex class definition. If your error is something else, i suggest you update the code and try to point out where it's failing.

Comment: @arut, I changed the code to remove any confusion so psRecordId is no longer there. I am now using recordId:this.recordId. (see code) What do you mean by there is no change in my apex class definition? Sorry, I am new to dev. In my Apex class, if I hard-code the recordId with i.e.: a0i8A000001zNjtQAE, it works like a charm but of course, this is not the goal. I need the Id to be pass to the function. I guess the recordId in my apex class is empty and this is why the insert is not working.

Comment: @Eric, Pls ignore my previous comment. I guess I hadn't refreshed the page before posting that comment, so didn't see your latest updated code.

Comment: What do the console.log statements display in the console window? Place `console.log(this.recordId)` as the first line of `submitAction` function & `system.debug(recordId)` as the first line of the apex method to observe what value you are getting for recordId. I believe there is no problem in your code in while passing the recordId from the component to apex method. The insert DML could be failing because of some other reason. Can you place try-catch block and check for any exception?

Comment: @arut, I used Chrome and I can see that the params is not empty. this.recordId is using the right id. This bring me to why my class is not using it through the params? I don't see how to debug my class from Chrome :(

Comment: Apex code executes on the server and you cannot debug it on the client i.e., chrome. As mentioned in my previous comment, use `System.debug` statement to observe some values and write a try-catch block. Read these for further understanding: [Exception handling example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_trycatch_example.htm?search_text=debug), [Debug Logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm); or simply google about apex debugging (there are many blogs that would help you).